# Update a data bound list box

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have a section of code that fires when a check box is checked/unchecked.
The check box is going to be used to narrow down a listbox that is data bound. One item in the data is a link to an png image which shows correctly when the application first initializes.
In the code below, I get a "Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' threw an exception" exception every time.

```
    Private Sub chkShowCurrent_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles chkShowCurrent.Click
    Dim o As ObjectDataProvider
    Dim xDoc = XDocument.Load(sFileName)

    If chkShowCurrent.IsChecked = False Then
        'MsgBox("false")
    End If

    If chkShowCurrent.IsChecked = True Then
        'MsgBox("true")
        Dim OnlyCurrent = From job In xDoc.Root.Descendants("Job")
                          Where job.Element("Status").Value = "a-current"
                          Order By job.Element("Status").Value, job.Element("Rush").Value, Convert.ToDateTime(job.Element("DateOut").Value)
                          Select job

        lstJobs.ItemsSource = OnlyCurrent

    End If
    lstJobs.Items.Refresh()
    o = FindResource("jobs")
    o.Refresh()
End Sub
```

I had originally thought that the lstjobs.items.refresh was the issue, but the exception doesn't popup until after End Sub has been reached. I have tried adding a breakpoint to the code at the checkbox code and step through the code, but the answer still eludes me. Can anyone tell me where my error is?

**** Edit for more info below ****

```
Public Property Artwork() As String
Get
    Return _Artwork
End Get
Set(ByVal value As String)
    If value = String.Empty Then value = "images\Untitled.png"

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("\\ARTSTATION\Users\Public\XML Job Board\" & value) Then
        value = "\\ARTSTATION\Users\Public\XML Job Board\" & value
    Else
        value = "\\ARTSTATION\Users\Public\XML Job Board\images\Untitled.png"
    End If
    _Artwork = value
End Set
```

The xml element  is formated as *image\GUID.png*, thus necessitating the need to add the full path at runtime.

I had originally explored this as the issue and changed the XML to contain the full path and commented out the need for adding the full path in the properties, but this yielded the same results.

Comment: Is the exception occurring on the lstJobs.Items.Refresh() or where?

Comment: If you've stepped through the code, what isn't firing when it should? You said the image loads correctly when the application first initializes, can you post that code? Also, your first `IF` statement has no code? Perhaps it's unnecessary?

Comment: @TonyHinkle, during F8 stepping, i had orginally thought that the lstjobs.items.refresh was the issue, but the exception doesn't popup until after End Sub has been reached.

Comment: That's important information--please include it in the question.

Comment: @alybaba726, I plan to edit the question to put in a little more detail. As for the first `IF`, it will be used to undo and restore the original state of the Listbox, but I wanted to nail down this issue first.

Comment: Question has been updated to include more info. I could really use the help on this one.